# How to create a distinct array that will re-arrange the elements and create new element from its value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, distinct

I'm trying to create a new element(not overwriting the data) using the value from the second element of my array(make it distinct) and using that element, it will enumerate it's value from the first element.

Let's say i have an array like below..

```
let arr = [
    {
        Name : 'Name 1'
        Details : [
            { DetailName : 'detail 1', DetailValue : 101 },
            { DetailName : 'detail 2', DetailValue : 101 },
            { DetailName : 'detail 3', DetailValue : 250 }
        ]
    },
    //Other Names & Details ...
];
```

Expected Output:

1. Check for duplicates value.
2. Sort all "DetailName" value and store in an array.
3. The "Value" will make an array that will have a value from "DetailName" (*distinct)

```
//Expected Output should be.
[
    {
        Name : 'Name 1'
        Details : [
            { 
                         101 : ['detail 1','detail 2'],
             250 : ['detail 3']     //where 101 & 250 is came from the "DetailValue" value, so it look likes an element from the value.
            }
        ]
    },
    //Other Names & Details ...
]
```

I tried to get their value first so by using this code.

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                let deita = arr[i].Details
                let removeDupsOfDetailValue = Object.keys(deita.reduce((r,{Length}) => (r[Length]=Length, r) , {}))
                console.log(removeDupsOfDetailValue)
            }
```

The above code show this arr ['101',250']. Although it removes the duplicate value i want to show also an array from DetailName , so the "101" element should have a value of array ['detail 1 , 'detail 2'] because it is an duplicate DetailValue.

Thank you for those who will answer my question. :)

Comment: Is there a need for Details to still be an array given that you are transforming the original from an array of objects into an array of a single object?

Comment: There is somehow i need it because i have many detail with the same value. I tried to make it in a way to easily check for the detail with same value. So let's say i have ten "101" value that are not in sequence, i can easily check for the details whose the same "101" value (ei. 'detail1', detail2', 'detail5','detail7,etc...),,

Comment: I'm not sure you're understanding my question.  To access a result with your desired output would be something like `result[0].Details[0]['101']` to return the array containing `['detail 1', 'detail 2']`.  But Details will never have more than one element after you do your modification.  So if you made Details just be the object, it would be accessible by `result[0].Details['101']` without the array that does not serve an observable purpose.

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding your question but, i tried to access the data from my array but it show it in a list on how the data is done, is there any way to sort it or in distinct so when i console.log it show the list of detail with same detailvalue? Please check this [][]CODE-> https://imgur.com/a/6RwLiqN [][]OUTPUT-> https://imgur.com/a/Jhd5MSj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I get the problem, but here what I'd do

```js
const res = arr.map(obj => {
  const keys = obj.Details.map(detail => detail.DetailValue)
  const newDetails = {}
  keys.forEach(
        key =>
            (newDetails[key] = obj.Details.filter(
                detail => detail.DetailValue === key
            )
                .map(x => x.DetailName)
                .sort())
    )
  return { ...obj, Details: [newDetails] }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a distinct array that re-arranges the elements and creates new elements from their values, you can follow these steps:

1. Start with an array of elements.
2. Create a new array to store the distinct elements.
3. Loop through each element in the original array.
4. Check if the element is already in the new array. If not, add it to the new array.
5. Create a new element by concatenating the value of the current element with a unique identifier such as an index value or a timestamp.
6. Add the new element to the new array.
7. Return the new array.

Here's an example implementation:

```
    function createDistinctArray(arr) {
        let distinctArr = [];

        arr.forEach((element, index) => {
            if (!distinctArr.includes(element)) {
                distinctArr.push(element);
        }

            let newElement = element + '_' + index;
            distinctArr.push(newElement);
            }
     );
         return distinctArr;
}
```

```
let originalArr = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'apple'];
let distinctArr = createDistinctArray(originalArr);

console.log(distinctArr); // Output: ['apple', 'apple_0', 'banana', 
'banana_1', 'cherry', 'cherry_2']
```

In this example, the function `createDistinctArray` takes an array as input and returns a new array with distinct elements and new elements created from their values. The `forEach` method is used to loop through each element in the original array. The includes method is used to check if the element is already in the new array. If not, the element is added to the new array. A new element is created by concatenating the value of the current element with the index of the current element. Finally, the new element is added to the new array. The output of the example is an array with distinct elements and new elements created from their values.